Weak form FEM discretisation of Non-Linear System
I am trying to derive the FEM solution for the equation $u''(x) + \left( u'(x) \right)^2=0$ with $u(1)=0, u'(0)=1$ over the interval $[0, 1]$.
Constrain the trial function, $v$, to also be zero at $x=1$.
$$\int_0^1{u''v + (u')^2v \ \mathrm{d} x} = 0$$
$$\int_0^1{u''v \ \mathrm{d} x} = vu'\Big|_0^1 - \int_0^1{u'v' \ \mathrm{d} x} =  - \int_0^1{u'v' \ \mathrm{d} x}$$
Therefore
$$\int_0^1{u'v' \ \mathrm{d} x} = \int_0^1{(u')^2v \ \mathrm{d} x}$$
Then, $u$ is appoximated to be the sum of linear shape functions: $u(x) \approx \sum_{i=0}^{N}{u_i \phi_i(x)}$.
However, I'm not sure how to apply the sum approximation for $u$ here? I'm okay doing it on the LHS, however on the RHS it doesn't simplify nicely, as $\left( \sum_{i=0}^{N}{u_i \phi_i'}\right)^2=\sum_{i=0}^{N}{u_i^3 (\phi_i')^3}$, so it would lead to a sum of cubes?
From there I can substitute in the shape functions for $v$, form the linear system of equations and solve for $u_{1,\cdots,N}$ as usual.

The equation is not linear, you probably need to consider iterative ideas or using Newton type method to find the solution.

Yimin is right. $(u'(x))^2$ term makes it nonlinear. That is why you are running into problems with simplifying the RHS.

look at $w = u'$ : $w' + w^2 = 0$, $w = -w'/w$ function equal to negative of own logarithmic derivative. $w = -log(w)'$  let $w=1/f$, $1/f = -ff'/f^2$, $f = -ff'$, $1 = -f'$, $f' = -1$, $f = c-x$, now to untangle the mess... $1/(c-x)$, then primitive function once again. $log(c-x) + c_2$

Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ denote the inner product on $L^2(0,1)$, then we do the following steps

Form the residual $F(u) = 0$.
Approximation $u$ and substitute: $F\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i\right)=0$
Project onto basis $\{\phi_0,\dots,\phi_N\}$ of test space: $\left \langle \phi_j, F\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i\right)\right\rangle =0 \ \forall \phi_j$.

One small note on the first part, your formulation does not enforce the nonhomogeneous boundary conditions. For simplicity, let $g$ be some function such that all of the requisite operators are defined that satisfies $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 1$. We will then define $\tilde{u}$ as the solution to your problem and solve for $u = \tilde{u} - g$ which satisfies homogeneous BCs.
You have already done the first part in the weak sense, which is fine:
$$
\langle v, F(u) \rangle = \int_0^1 u'v'+g'v' -(u'+g')^2v~dx.
$$
We now substitute the finite element approximation for $u$ to obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left \langle v, F\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i\right)\right\rangle &= \int_0^1\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i'\right)v' + g'v'-\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i' + g'\right)^2v~dx
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, we force this expression to be zero for all $v\in\mathrm{span}\{\phi_0,\dots,\phi_N\}$, which is equivalent to making it zero for every basis element. We then have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left \langle \phi_j, F\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i\right)\right\rangle &= \int_0^1\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i'\right)\phi_j'  + g'\phi_j'-\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i' + g'\right)^2\phi_j~dx.
\end{aligned}
$$
We now define the function $\mathbf{F}:\mathbb{R}^{N+1}\to\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ by
$$
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u}) = \begin{pmatrix}\left\langle \phi_0, F\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i\right)\right\rangle \\ \vdots \\ \left\langle \phi_N, F\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i\right)\right\rangle \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} \displaystyle \int_0^1\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i'\right)\phi_0' + g'\phi_0-\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i' + g'\right)^2\phi_0~dx\\ \vdots \\ \displaystyle \int_0^1\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i'\right)\phi_N' + g'\phi_N'-\left(\sum_{i=0}^N u_i \phi_i' + g'\right)^2\phi_N~dx\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\mathbf{u} = (u_0,\dots,u_N)^T\in\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$. By solving $\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u})=\mathbf{0}$ using something like Newton's method, we solve the Galerking problem. It remains to be seen how to properly express $\mathbf{F}$ and its derivatives in any sensible way. For this purpose, we define the following tensors of ranks 1, 2, and 3:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{b_0} &= \begin{pmatrix}\langle \phi_0', g'\rangle \\ \vdots \\ \langle \phi_N', g'\rangle \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\displaystyle \int_0^1 g'\phi_0'~dx \\ \vdots \\ \displaystyle \int_0^1 g'\phi_N'~dx \end{pmatrix}\\ 
\mathbf{R^{00}}&= \begin{pmatrix}\langle (g')^2, \phi_0\rangle \\ \vdots \\ \langle (g')^2, \phi_N\rangle \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\displaystyle \int_0^1 (g')^2\phi_0~dx \\ \vdots \\ \displaystyle \int_0^1 (g')^2\phi_N~dx \end{pmatrix}\\ 
~\\
\mathbf{K}_{jk} &= \langle \phi_j',\phi_k' \rangle = \int_0^1 \phi_i'\phi_j'~dx \\
\mathbf{R^{u0}}_{jk}&= \langle \phi_j' g', \phi_k \rangle\\
\mathbf{R^{0u}}_{jk}&= \langle g' \phi_j', \phi_k \rangle\\
\mathbf{R^{u0}} &= \mathbf{R^{0u}}
~\\
\mathbf{R^{uu}}_{ijk} &= \langle \phi_i'\phi_j',\phi_k\rangle = \int_0^1\phi_i'\phi_j'\phi_k~dx.
\end{aligned}
$$
We now have a tidy tensor equation given by
$$
\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{u}) = \mathbf{K}\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{b_0} - \mathbf{R^{00}} - 2\mathbf{R^{u0}}\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{R^{uu}}[\mathbf{u},\mathbf{u}] = \mathbf{0},
$$
where the last term is understood in the sense that $\mathbf{R}[e_i,e_j,e_k] = \langle \phi_i'\phi_j',\phi_k\rangle$ and we are applying tensor contraction over the first two indices. From this, we can also obtain a simple expression for the Jacobian-vector product to be used in Newton's method. Let $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ denote an arbitrary direction, then the Jacobian-vector product is given by
$$
\mathbf{JF}(\mathbf{u})\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{K}\mathbf{w} - 2\mathbf{R}^{u0}\mathbf{w}-\mathbf{R^{uu}}[\mathbf{u},\mathbf{w}] - \mathbf{R^{uu}}[\mathbf{w},\mathbf{u}].
$$
This particular tensor happens to be symmetric in the first two components, so these could be combined as $-2\mathbf{R}[\mathbf{w},\mathbf{u}]$. This could be used in a matrix-free Newton Krylov iteration or you could actually form these matrices in memory and use a standard Newton iteration.
